Equivalent definition of continuous spectrum and residual spectrum
Here are two definitions of continuous spectrum I have encountered.
Given a bounded linear operator $T$.
Here are the definition given in Kreyszig's book: given a complex normed space $X$,
denote
$(R2)$ $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded.
$(R3)$ $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ defined on a set which is dense in $X$.
$\sigma_{c}(T)$ is the set such that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and satisfies $(R3)$ but not $(R2)$.
Another definition: (for example, in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis))
$\sigma_{c}(T)$ is the set of those $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $T-\lambda I$ is injective, $\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda I)$ is dense, but $T-\lambda I$ is not surjective.
I can see why we required $\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda I)$ is dense (to satisfy $R3$, but I don't see why the last definition would imply $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ being unbounded.
This is not answered in Meaning of terminologies "regular value", "point spectrum", "continous spectrum" and "residual spectrum"

In the case that $X$ is Banach and $T$ is closed it follows as follows by contradiction:
Assume that $(T- \lambda I )^{-1}$ is bounded.
It is easily verified that $(T- \lambda I)^{-1}$ is closed (because $T$ is).
Let $x \in X$. Then, by assumption, there exist a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in the domain of $(T- \lambda I)^{-1}$ with $x_n \to x$.
Since $(T- \lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded it follows that $((T- \lambda I)^{-1}x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence, by the completness of $X$ it is convergent to $y \in X$.
But since the graph of $(T- \lambda I)^{-1}$ is closed we must have that $x$ is in the domain of $(T- \lambda I)^{-1}$ and that $y= (T- \lambda I)^{-1}x$.
Hence $(T-\lambda I )^{-1}$ is defined everywhere and so $T-\lambda I$ is surjective (contrary to the assumption).

Thanks! Just edited.

@Dinoman No worries. Ideally you should also add to your question what exactly $T$ is. I guessed from the context that its some linear operator, but its not really clear from the body of your question.
